# How can I manipulate the DOM from a string of HTML in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm developing a Windows 8 Metro App using JavaScript. I need to manipulate a string of HTML to select elements like DOM.

How can I do that?

Example:

```
var html = data.responseText; // data.response is a string of HTML received from xhr function.
// Now I need to extract an element from the string like document.getElementById("some_element")...
```

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

I solved!

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var xml = parser.parseFromString(data.responseText);
```

Comment: Whatever you're thinking about doing, this is not the way to do it. I'm almost 100% sure you can do it some other way. I suggest that you explain what you're trying to do a bit more.

Comment: Try response instead of responseText, that should be a DOM-parsed snippet for which you can execute DOM queries against. Note, this only works if the response type (data.responseType) is set to 'document'

Comment: How can I set the response type to "document"?

Answer (score 3):

I think your approach to the problem isn't the best, you could return [JSON](http://www.json.org/) or xml. But if you need to do it that way:

To my knowledge you wont be able to use `getElementById` without inserting a new element in the document (in the example below, doing inserting `div` in `document`, for example `document.appendChild(div)`), but you could do this:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = '<span id="rawr"></span>'; //here you would put data.responseText

var elements = div.getElementsByTagName("span"); // [<span id="rawr"></span>], there you could ask elements[0].id === "rawr" or whatever you like
```

Comment: I can't inject HTML dynamically when the App is running... but thanks!

Comment: You can add HTML dynamically, you just need to wrap it with the function `toStaticHTML(//string)`

Comment: can u tell me hw 2 parse xml string in windows 8 using JS